# No Animation UITableViewCell selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I have a UITableView that when the cells are touched, another view slides over top of the cell. However, the selected cell does the selection animation, which causes interference with sliding view. I'd like to stop the cell from the background-changing selection animation from happening. So no background change on select. Is there a way to do this simply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change cell `selectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`

Comment: In my case - occurred, when edited `cell.selectedBackgroundView`. Without the line from the answer - no selection animation at all.